# Convergence of expectations under almost everywhere convergence and uniform integrability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

Prove that if a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, and if the $X_n$ are uniformly integrable (UI), then 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  E[X_n] = E[X].
$$
Can you please help with this question?

Converges in Distribution means 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(X_n \leq a) = P(X \leq a)
$$

$X_n$ is UI if $\sup_nE(|X_n|^{1+\epsilon} < \infty$

I have to use Skorohod Theorem to construct $Y_n$ and Y then $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ a.s

so I have to show 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  E[Y_n] = E[Y].
$$

How can I show that in details?

Thank you

Comment: If you outline some of your thinking on this, people might be more willing to help. Write down what convergence in distribution means in mathematical terms, maybe in terms of density or distribution functions. Write down what uniform integrability means in mathematical terms. Write down those expectations as integrals and apply the limit. If you put this reasoning in your question, we can identify where you are stuck and help you finish the proof.

Comment: That's better. Now, do you know the definition of the expectation in terms of integrals and probability densities or distribution functions?

Comment: This is not "outlining your thinking", but randomly copying some definitions from your lectures (with an error for UI, which is not what you write).

Comment: Thank you Rajb245 yes I know the definition in terms of integrals and probability density function but I am not sure if this is the root I have to go down.  I an sorry Did I did explain how I started and where I got stuck, and You are wrong about the UI this is one way to define UI yes there is something else which is the tail of converge integral converge to zero. So please if you have better comment to say do it other than stay out of it

Comment: There are many ways to show this, I had one in mind. In any case you might be able to follow along with the proof here:
http://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/275b.1.12w/lect10-web.pdf

Comment: Sorry it is not so clear how to follow the proof. Can you send me peter proof? Thank you

Comment: "this is one way to define UI" Sorry, but this is wrong. (Unrelated: next time, try to use @.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Skorohod theorem, then you are actually reduced to show the following lemma:

> If $(Z_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a uniformly integrable sequence which converges almost everywhere to $Z$, then $\mathbb E(Z_n)\to\mathbb E(Z)$.

This is an extension of dominated convergence theorem. To the lemma is true, use dominated convergence theorem with $(Z_n\chi_{|Z_n|\leqslant R})_{n\geqslant 1}$ for a well chosen $R$.